# Cordova IOS not using NSMotionUsageDescription values

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am updating one of our Cordova apps so everything is up-to-date for IOS and Android.
One of the things I ran into for IOS is the requirement that you have to ask for motion permission.
I was able to get the app to ask for the permission, but unlike the other permissions I am unable to customize the text.

The text is now as follows:

> "localhost" Would Like to Access Motion and Orientation

But other permissions show the name of my app in stead of "localhost" and a description which I provided in the config.xml
I did provide a description in the config.xml and even added a description manually in the info.plist file in Xcode, but nothing helps.

I am using Ionic 6.9.2, Cordova 9.0.0 and added the ios@5.1.1 platform to Cordova.

Does anyone now how I can provide a description and fix the "localhost" in the Motion permission request?

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is an old issue, but I hope this answer would be helpful.

you need to comment/remove on some block of code on `leaflet.locatecontrol` inside `node_modules` folder.
first go to `node_modules -> leaflet.locatecontrol -> src` and open file `L.Control.Locate.js`, then comment/remove following code:

```
if (this.options.showCompass) {
    var oriAbs = 'ondeviceorientationabsolute' in window;
    if (oriAbs || ('ondeviceorientation' in window)) {
        var _this = this;
        var deviceorientation = function () {
            L.DomEvent.on(window, oriAbs ? 'deviceorientationabsolute' : 'deviceorientation', _this._onDeviceOrientation, _this);
        };
        if (DeviceOrientationEvent && typeof DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission === 'function') {
            DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission().then(function (permissionState) {
                if (permissionState === 'granted') {
                    deviceorientation();
                }
            });
        } else {
            deviceorientation();
        }
    }
}
```